# Codeigniter repeating view loader

Tags: codeigniter, repeat

I noticed when dealing with Codeigniter controllers that I seem to get a lot of repeating code.  More precisely whenever I am loading a view.  So lets say I have a controller called login which have the following index method:

```
$data['title'] = 'Login';
$data['main_content'] = 'forms/login';
$this->load->view('frontpage', $data);
```

Then I have a frontpage controller with the following index method:

```
$data['title'] = 'Welcome';
$data['main_content'] = 'content/welcome';
$this->load->view('frontpage', $data);
```

As pretty much the only thing that changes is what is inside $data I was wondering if there is some way to make these a more general code so any code repeat would be eliminated.

I have been toying with the idea of either creating a seperate method to handle this (pass the $data as parameter and let the method to the viewloading) or initializing the $data array before in the class and just changing the content with $this->.  I'd like some professional opinion on this.  Am I even on the right track with my way of thinking?

Comment: I don't see any repeating code, can you show us? Do you mean you have the same title for every call to the controller? (hardly...)

Comment: @jtheman what I mean is that the only thing that changes in my controllers is the contents of the $data array so I can have two different controllers with almost identical code barring the contents of the $data array.  As such I have multiple controllers with each having the same $this->load->view('frontpage', $data) call .

Comment: For my own code I normally only have one controller method for each view template. (If I have repeating code in the views I use includes there instead, like templates for header, footer etc). This way also the view files is much simplified with minimal logic.

Comment: You COULD shorten the data array syntax: `$d=array('title'=>'Login','main_content'=>'forms/login'); $this->load->view('frontpage',$d);`

Comment: HMVC removes all repeated widget codes. Template library by Phil Sturgeon removes all $this->load->view()'s. Look it up

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have separate views for each "view". This approach both simplifies your controller and remove need for (messy) logic in your view files:

```
public function index()
{
  $data['title'] = 'Welcome';
  $this->load->view('content/welcome', $data);
}

public function login()
{
  $data['title'] = 'Login';
  $this->load->view('forms/login', $data);
}
```

Then use includes in your view file to add headers etcetera.

(example views/forms/login.php)

```
<?php include(APPPATH.'/views/includes/header.php'); ?>

<!--login form ....  -->

<?php include(APPPATH.'/views/includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

(Note: No need for logic inside view: `if ($main_content == 'forms/login'):` etcetera...)

Comment: This I already have and the only content that changes is the 'main_content' part which tells the template page which content view to load (whether its the welcome screen or login form).  Am I nitpicking here for trying to eliminate too much code repeat?

Comment: Yes, well, one intention of the MVC structure is to take away logic from view files. Doing this fully (havin only ONE controller method per view) would both eliminate code in your view AND controller...

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding what he's doing. He has a template system the only difference between your code and his is yours isn't loading the template part he needs. There is no view logic involved.

Comment: @rickcalder Cool, still no easy way around the repeating code issue!

Comment: Yep, in the end I do believe he's taking the DRY method just a little too far lol